# Price(float number) in transactional email

Tags: email, email-templates

If i put in email template {{var order.shipping_amout}} i will get it like : 12.00000

How i can make it normal (ex. 12.00) ?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The typical way to handle this is to create a custom block which, when rendered, will call the core currency formatter for you:

```
{{block type="custom/currency" template="folder/template.phtml" order=$order }}
```

Which will output the contents of whatever module is mapped to the block shortcode of `custom`, e.g. `YourCompany_YourModule_Block_Currency`.

In that template file to get access to the $order object do:

```
<?php $order=$this->getOrder() ?>
```

And then you can call the currency formatter on the shipping amount:

```
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($order->getShippingAmount(),false,false);
```

**Another way:**

If my memory serves correctly, starting in 1.4CE+ you could "pipe" values to an escape function in Magento. Something akin to {{var name|escape}} in the email template output.

No other filter modifiers exist natively, but you could create them by extending `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`. That would look like:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Email_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->_modifiers['formatCurrency'] = array($this, 'modifierFormatCurrency');
    }

    public function modifierFormatCurrency($var)
    {
        return Mage::helper('core')->currency($var,false,false);
    }

}
```

Now you can do something like `{{var order.shipping_amount|formatCurrency}}` :)

Cheers.

Comment: Great answer, however in your second example, it's not enough to extend it, you need to rewrite the core model in config.xml

Comment: are you serious? All that to format a digit????